# UIView Animate animating when it's not supposed to

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I want to move an `UIImageView` on the screen from one point to another with an animation. When the image gets to the point I want, it's supposed to reappear on another point without any animation. I tried different methods, but I was expecting this one to be the best method :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
            image.center = CGPointMake(40, 15); }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             image.center = CGPointMake(900, 500);
                             }];
```

But what happens is when the image was supposed to reappear on the point 900x,500y it animates its way through there. I even tried things like :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
            image.center = CGPointMake(40, 15); }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             image.hidden=YES;
                             if (image.isHidden) {
                             image.center = CGPointMake(1600, RandomPosition);
                             }
                         }];
```

But nothing seems to work! I really feel like a noob, because this has got to be really simple, and maybe it is and I'm just doing it wrong. 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
image.center = CGPointMake(40, 15);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        image.center = CGPointMake(900, 500); }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         ;
                         }];
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what I want, I want to animate to the point 40x,15y and not animate to 900x 500y!

Comment: @Mykod I'm sorry about my wrong answer.I created a new project and ran your code above,there is nothing wrong about the code.I'm sorry I can't help you.